# Invariant vector field (under translation) are constants.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

**Example 8.40** (Introduction to smooth manifolds. Lee)

If we consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a Lie group under addition, left translation by an element $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by the affine map $L_b(x)=b+x$, whose differential $d(L_b)$ is represented by the identity matrix in standard coordinates. Thus a vector field $X^i \partial_{x_i}$ is left-invariant if and only if its coefficients $X^i$ are constants.

**Question 1**. Why $X^i$ are constants?

My attempt: $X^i(x)\left.\partial_{x_i}\right|_{x}=X^i(b+x)\left.\partial_{x_i}\right|_{b+x}$

Comment: When you apply both sides to the function $f(x)=x_i$ what follows?

Comment: $X^i(x)=X^i(b+x)$? then $X^i(x)=constant$?

Comment: Quite obviously.

Comment: but $\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(x)$ and $\sin$ is not contant. What is my wrong? thanks

Comment: Your relation holds for every $b\,.$

Comment: oh thanks i see